# jQuery class selector for SVG in XHTML

Tags: jquery, svg

The following code works (in console you can see two log messages as the elements detected) if the file is named as *.html, but the elements are not selected if I name to *.xhtml.  Why do these behave differently? The issue is only when the class name is included in the selector, so `$("#cvs rect")` works in both case,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head> 
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
  <svg id="cvs" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 100" version="1.1" baseProfile="full">
    <rect class="drag resize" x="50" y="30" width="50" height="30" />
    <rect class="drag resize" x="5"  y="5"  width="90" height="50" />
  </svg>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
      $("#cvs rect.resize").each(function() {
        console.log("selected");
      }); 
    }); 
  </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Try to use my jQuery hack [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792754/create-and-access-svg-tag-with-jquery/14985470#14985470][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792754/create-and-access-svg-tag-with-jquery/14985470#14985470

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks to be a ~bug in jQuery or Sizzle. Here's a pared-down test case showing the problem:

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" /> 
  <title>Create SVG Elements HTML</title> 
</head><body> 
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
    <circle r="200" class="face" fill="red" /> 
  </svg> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    console.log( document.getElementsByClassName('face').length );    // 1
    console.log( document.querySelectorAll('circle.face').length );   // 1
    console.log( $('circle').length );                                // 1
    console.log( $('.face').length );                                 // 0
    console.log( $('circle.face').length );                           // 0
    console.log( $('circle[class~="face"]').length );                 // 1
  ]]></script> 
</body></html>
```

*Results are consistent across Chrome v11, Firefox v4, Safari v5, and IE9.*

The problem appears to be that jQuery is not properly querying `class` attributes on elements within another namespace. Using the ["attribute contains word" selector `~=`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/) you can use jQuery to find these elements.

**Edit**: The root cause of this is likely documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294553/jquery-selector-svg-incompatible/5759456#5759456); summarized, the problem is that SVG DOM specifies that the `class` attribute (as with many other) is not a static value accessible via `className`, but rather an `SVGAnimatedString` which has `.baseVal` and `.animVal` properties needed to fetch the actual string value of the class.

Comment: thank you, I will report to the jQuery mailing list.. thanks again for the effort..

Comment: @bsreekanth See my updated answer for a workaround query that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<rect>
```

elements are not self-closing, these lines need closing:-

```
 <rect> </rect>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think *.xhtml is a valid extension; XHTML is usually used within a standard .htm or .html file anyway, just specify it in your doctype.

http://www.webheadstart.org/xhtml/faq/index.html

Comment: well I saw here, i could use that extension as well. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XHTML/A_Basic_XHTML_Document#File_Extension .. not sure what is reliable.. anyway, will wait for more opinion.. thanks for the help

Comment: `.xhtml` is **the** extension for XHTML documents. Servers that understand `.xhtml` files will serve them as `application/xhtml+xml`, browsers will also try to validate them before displaying. When XHTML lives in an `.html` or `.htm` file, it's usually served as `text/html`, which we've been doing for years without realizing it's a mistake.