# bind click events to document within object tag by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, tags, click

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery + SVG object: Capture click event properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237995/jquery-svg-object-capture-click-event-properly)

Suppose there is an html like this

```
<html>
<body>
<object data="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ....>...</svg>"></object>
...
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('click', function(e){
        console.log("clicked");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The click event is working everywhere other than the loaded svg image. It is possible to bind the click event to this image as well.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @eicto, the solution in the specified link will solve the problem.