# Why doesn't Twitter Bootstrap popover work with SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I'm more of a C++ guy, but I am working on some web UI stuff at the moment. I can't seem to get a Bootstrap popover to show up on an SVG element.

Any ideas? The popover works on the normal div.

jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/JjAht/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle r="45" cx="50" cy="50" style="fill: red"/>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="well">
    <p>
    Hover here for a popover.
    </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var numCircles = $("circle").length;
        console.log("numCircles = " + numCircles);

        $("circle").popover({trigger:'hover', placement:'bottom', title:'Title!', content:'Content'});

        $("circle").css({"stroke":"blue"});

        $(".well").popover({trigger:'hover', placement:'bottom', title:'Title!', content:'Content'});
    } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294553/jquery-selector-svg-incompatible
However, I could not make their solution work on FF15.

Comment: Ah, so the answer is that SVG has a similar but incompatible API and Bootstrap/jQuery can't deal with it. Lovely. Looks like I'll have to roll my own pop-up.

[This example](http://markhansen.co.nz/stolen-vehicles-pt2/) uses the Bootstrap popover (I think), but I can't follow all the code.

Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 25):

From that example it looks like you need to modify Bootstrap to get this to work.

Under bootstrap-tooltip.js replace:

```
$tip
    .detach()
    .css({ top: 0, left: 0, display: 'block' })
    .insertAfter(this.$element)

pos = this.getPosition(inside)
```

with

```
if($('#'+this.$element[0].id,$('svg')).length > 0){
        $tip
          .remove()
          .css({ top: 0, left: 0, display: 'block' })
          .prependTo(document.body)

        pos = $.extend({}, this.$element.offset(), {
          width: this.$element[0].getBoundingClientRect().width
          , height: this.$element[0].getBoundingClientRect().height
        })
   } else {
         $tip
             .detach()
             .css({ top: 0, left: 0, display: 'block' })
             .insertAfter(this.$element)

         pos = this.getPosition(inside)
    }
```

There were basically two problems 1) bootstrap was inserting the div for the tooltip/popover into the SVG where the browser ignores it and 2) the position information needs to be calculated from the SVG

I've submitted this as a pull request on Github https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6521

**Update:** It looks like bootstrap 2.3.0+ will support this via a new `container` property for tooltips/popovers. When working with SVG, set the `container` to `body`. See comments here https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6521

An example:

```
svg.selectAll(".node").each(
    function(d,i){
        $(this).popover({title:"title", content:"content", container:"body"});
        // and/or $(this).tooltip({title:"tooltip - title", container:"body"});
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I see you're in Alexandria; I'm in DC. I'd gladly buy you a happy hour beer sometime next week. You can email me at jon@lightboxtechnologies.com.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tricks. Adding container options is working for me. Note: I'm using it to display popup on Openlayer ...

Comment: One other useful parameter is 'viewport'. This keeps the popover within the bounds of this element. I typically set this to the container SVG element

Answer (score 16):

With the latest version of Bootstrap, adding a `container` option with an HTML element inside seems to be enough to make it work!

```
$("circle").each(function () {
    $(this).popover({
        title: "Hi!",
        content: "popover",
        container: $("#container")
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess it would be better to change the container to `container: "body`.. BTW, good solution there..

Answer (score -1):

you haven't selected the svg to open a popover, that's why it won't open. Look here http://jsfiddle.net/JjAht/1/

```
    $("svg").popover({trigger:'hover', placement:'bottom', title:'Title!', content:'Content'});
```

Comment: This opens a popover on the SVG as a whole, but, to be clear, what I'd ideally like is a popover on elements inside the svg. For example, if I had two circles, I'd like different popovers for each.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to make 2 svg then?

Comment: I'll have a few thousand SVG elements, each representing a unique data point. I'd like the popover to present information about the unique data point. Putting each element into a separate SVG container doesn't seem feasible. [This site](http://markhansen.co.nz/stolen-vehicles-pt2/) is a good example of what I want do... fortunately, one can read the source for it. :-)