# Jquery not selector is being ignored with svg

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-selectors

Trying to change the color on all the paths in an svg group except one path that has been given the class "static".  I have tried both of the following:

```
$('.groupClass').children().not('.static').css('fill', '#FF0')
```

In this case, the not selector is ignored.  All layers change color.

I have also tried:

```
$('.groupClass').children('not(.static)').css('fill', '#FF0')
```

In this case, color change stops working.

You can see the actual project here, to see the svg structure: http://www.thelionscall.com/wp-content/Temp/  i am trying to change the color on only the bloom of the rose.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: SVG Dom doesn't play nice w jQuery selectors. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5759456/165673

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorten it up a bit:

```
$(".groupClass :not(.static)").css("fill", "#FF0");
```

Comment: This turned out to be the one that worked.  Maybe something about the way SVG is structured.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The selector is preceded by a `:`

```
$('.groupClass').children().filter(':not(.static)').css('fill', '#FF0')
```

or simply:

```
$('.groupClass').children().not('.static').css('fill', '#FF0')
```

Comment: deleted my answer because apparently we had the same idea with the second one you provided. you should make it your primary; its far more efficient than the former.

Comment: thats decent of you. i am just keeping it like that so you see the difference and the OP can see the "better" version towards his plan

Comment: As @PlantTheIdea said, `.not()` is the better (faster) choice.

Comment: I mistyped my post, showing the same method twice.  I've tried this second version already.  It's changing all the colors, and not ignoring the path I want it to.

Comment: well maybe the .static elements are not children but rather deeper nested. instead of children() do .find('*'). always hard to tell without any code provided..

Comment: @KristiSimonson then you should fix the question also post the svg structure so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: And using the filter method has the same result.  It's like it doesn't see the class...here's the actual project.  You'll have to use the arrow button to select the rose item and try changing the color.  I'm trying to leave the leaf green while the bloom changes color...unless I've placed the class in completely the wrong path?  http://www.thelionscall.com/wp-content/Temp/

Comment: I've tried it in both IE and Firefox.  The leaf changes color with the rose...it should remain green.

Comment: well your structure does not show any .groupClass, how shall we help you then!?