# How to target an item in an iframe with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, svg

How do I target and item in an iframe thats on my site and change the inline value?

```
<iframe class="preview_iframe">
<div id="example">
<a id="ex">
<svg fill="#000000"></svg>
</a>
</div>
</iframe>
```

I need to target an SVG (multiple) in an iframe and change the fill (color) with jquery, how can I do this I tried but it doesn't seem to select it.

Heres the jquery im trying

> ```
>          $("[id^=like_iframe_]").load(function() {
>             var frame = $("[id^=like_iframe_]").contents();
>             $("svg", frame).css({'fill' : 'red'});
>            });
> ```

And

```
$("[id^=like_iframe_]").contents().find("svg").css({'fill' : 'red'});
```

Its selecting the frame, but it's not changing the color of the svg

Comment: This may have less to do with the `iframe` and more to do with the `svg`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294553/jquery-selector-svg-incompatible

Comment: "I tried but it doesn't seem to select it." What have you tried? What does not select what? Where is the JS?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following (see below) works for me:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Downloads/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">function tryit(){
  $("iframe[id$=iframe]").contents().find("ellipse").css({fill:"red"});
}</script>
</head><body>
<a href="#" onclick='tryit()'>click here</a><br/>
<iframe id="preview_iframe" src="stackoverflow19846765_iframe.html">
This text won't show if browser supports IFRAMEs(?).</iframe>
</body></html>
```

File stackoverflow19846765_iframe.html reads:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<div id="example"> <a id="ex" onclick="alert('clicked svg')">
<svg fill="#000000"> 
  <ellipse cx="110" cy="60" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:blue" />
</svg>
</a> </div>
</body></html>
```

I had to use a `src` attribute for the `iframe` (and put the source in a separate file). (Otherwise the `iframe` appeared empty.)

The selector on `id` does not seem to match(?) the HTML fragment (using `class`) in your code. I used `iframe id=` and selected it with `id*=iframe`.

I had to put something within the `svg` to see anything happen.

NOTE: When trying the code with local files, only Firefox lets me look into the `iframe`. Chrome prevents that due to same origin policy on local files.