# Adding CSS to an iframe element

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, svg

How do I target and item in an iframe thats on my site and change the inline value?

```
<iframe class="preview_iframe">
<div id="example">
<a id="ex">
<svg fill="#000000"></svg>
</a>
</div>
</iframe>
```

I need to target an SVG (multiple) in an iframe and change the fill (color) with jquery, how can I do this I tried these they don't seem to work

Heres the jquery im trying

```
$("[id^=like_iframe_]").load(function() {
  var frame = $("[id^=like_iframe_]").contents();
  $("svg", frame).css({'fill' : 'red'});
});
```

And

```
$("[id^=like_iframe_]").contents().find("svg").css({'fill' : 'red'});
```

Its selecting the frame, but it's not changing the color of the svg

Heres a link
http://absdfsderedfdsfrr.tumblr.com/ to see what im working on

Comment: `frame.find("svg").css({'fill' : 'red'});`

Comment: Nope, it did not work

Comment: can you log the number of svg found? `console.log(frame.find("svg").size());`

Comment: Is there a reason why your using an iframe and not canvas?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are not making any cross-domain requests for the iframe's content? Modern browsers will not allow you to manipulate cross-domain content within an iframe (this would be cross-site scripting, which is a security vulnerability).

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: I just realize that was happening, is there anyway I can manipulate the color of that item?

Comment: No. Modern browsers will not allow you to access or manipulate these elements for security reasons. For ways around the same-origin policy, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy?lq=1

Comment: Also, please do not make duplicate question listings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846765/how-to-target-an-item-in-an-iframe-with-jquery ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 0):

try this sry have not sandbox to check;

```
$('.preview_iframe').get(0).find("svg").css({'fill' : 'red'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a class and use .attr() to change the fill like

```
$('.class').attr('fill', 'color');
```

Answer (score 0):

`<svg fill="#000000"></svg>`

"fill" isn't a CSS style, that's an attribute on svg.

It should actually look something like this:

`$("[id^=like_iframe_]").contents().find("svg").attr('fill', '#FF0000');`

As explained on jQuery's documentation (http://api.jquery.com/attr/), .attr can get or set an attribute on a tag. The above code should be roughly what you're looking for.

EDIT: Jimmy makes a good point, you should probably add a class to the iframe as well.

Comment: "fill" **is** a valid CSS property, but it only applies to SVGs.  It is valid to include it in style sheets.

Comment: I actually was going to include a comment about how I wasn't sure if it was possible to update SVG's using CSS or not, I was mainly referring to the fact that, in context, fill here was being used as an attribute and it'd probably be best to change the fill value using attr.