# SVG - click is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an element like this.

```
<g id="box_w" onclick="recordResponseKeyboard('W');" onmousedown="svgFill('W');" onmouseup="svgUnfill('W');"> 
    <rect fill="#FFFFFF" height="68.522" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="119.297" x="306.673" y="384.406"></rect> 
</g>
```

From the chrome console, I can do to locate the element.

```
document.getElementById('box_w')
```

If i call click event,

```
document.getElementById('box_w').click()
```

It throws an error that click is not a function.

How to click on the element using console.?

Comment: try `$('#box_w').click()`

Comment: Why not just call the function directly?

Comment: click() is a [HTML method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click), it's not available for SVG elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `onclick` instead of `click`.

```
document.querySelector("g#box_w").onclick();
```

Remember that what we are doing here is calling the interface of the shape. So `onclick` needs to be defined in svg as it is in the question:

```html
<g id="box_w" onclick="recordResponseKeyboard('W');"></g>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work when targeting a rect with an id in Chrome 64.0.3282.186

Comment: this just doesn't work at all. `onclick is not a function`

Comment: pay attention that his shape has such function `onclick="recordResponseKeyboard('W');"`

Answer (score 15):

click() is a function that's only defined on HTML elements. Fortunately it's a convenience function and we can implement it ourselves pretty easily i.e.

```
document.getElementById('box_w').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

That's all the click() function does underneath the hood anyway.

Here's an example:

```js
document.getElementById('box_w').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

```html
<g id="box_w" onclick="alert('hi')"> 
    <rect fill="#FFFFFF" height="68.522" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="119.297" x="306.673" y="384.406"></rect> 
</g>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer