# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).click is not a function

Tags: javascript, click

Getting the error, Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).click is not a function tried to refer to a similar question but unable to solve it.

```
function zoom() {
 var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value; //value from searchbox
console.log(input);
 d3.json("intervals.json", function(alldata)  // entering json file  to look for oid
 {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < alldata.records.length; i++)  //for loop for getting the oid
    {

      conceptid = alldata.records[i].oid;  //saving all the oid in conceptid
      console.log(document.getElementById("l" + conceptid.toString()).textContent);


      if (document.getElementById("l" + conceptid.toString()).textContent === input)
      {

        document.getElementById("l" + conceptid.toString()).click();
      }

    }

 });
}
```

Comment: add `console.log(document.getElementById("l" + conceptid.toString()));` before the call to click() and inspect the element in the console. Maybe there is no click function or it has been ovewritten with something else.

Comment: Its giving me this  -   ```<text x="633.1635597073879" y="80" width="47.419212341308594" height="20" class="fullName level3" id="l15" style="display: block; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Jurassic</text>```  . But also giving an error timescale.js:518 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).click is not a function. Line 518 is  ```document.getElementById("l" + conceptid.toString()).click(); ```

Comment: SVG-Elements are not of type HTMLElement, so they do not support that method. Sorry I meant `console.dir(...)`. If you use that you can see for yourself that the method does not exist on that element.

Comment: Does this work? `document.getElementById("l" + conceptid.toString()).dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))`

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787804/3082296) on why `click` doesn't work on svg elements